# Fastest way of list comprehension while calculating the distance with a fixed list

Tags: python, list, iteration, list-comprehension, cosine-similarity

I have a list,

```
 a = [1,2,3]
```

Now I have another list of lists(which is same size as above),

```
x=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Now I want to calculate the distance between each item in x with a them using cosine distance so I am using this,

```
from scipy import spatial
distances = [spatial.distance.cosine(a, i) for i in x]
```

Now the above method is taking very long time to execute, I am looking for alternative way to do this most efficiently.

Comment: I doubt that the list comprehension is what's taking time...

Comment: There is nothing here to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

With numpy, you can use broadcasting to do the same computation and take advantage of vectorized operations for more efficiency.

```py
def cosine_distance(a, x):
    a = np.array(a)
    x = np.array(x)
    return 1 - x.dot(a) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1))
```

Using ipython's `%timeit` for the example data to compare the execution time:

```
%timeit [spatial.distance.cosine(a, i) for i in x]
140 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit cosine_distance(a, x)
27.8 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: its the correct solution i tested it on 100000 samples 10x faster results on core i5 16gb ram

Comment: AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: If you convert your input arrays to numpy, what are their shapes?